# Insert a field in the table that depends of the values previously set

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `Flights`. This table has the following structure:

```
+----+----------+---------------+
| Id |   Name   | DepartureDate |
+----+----------+---------------+
|  1 | 20130001 | 2013-02-14    |
|  2 | 20130002 | 2013-05-04    |
|  3 | 20140001 | 2014-01-16    |
|  4 | 20130003 | 2013-07-15    |
|  5 | 20150001 | 2015-01-01    |
|  6 | 20150002 | 2015-09-14    |
+----+----------+---------------+
```

As you can see, flight's name depends of the year of the departure date and a correlative number.

The problem is that when I want to insert a flight in, i.e. 2013, I have to make a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query to get the quantity of flights of that year in this table and then make the `INSERT INTO` statement. I think this is terrible and inefficient, because it could be duplicated flight numbers.

What do you recommend to make this operation?

Comment: That's not what I want to do, I already do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used a trigger event using the suggestions of @Alex.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `flights_iu_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `flights` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE flight_name INT;
    SELECT (IFNULL(MAX(Name), CONCAT(YEAR(NEW.DepartureDate),'0000')) + 1) 
    INTO flight_name FROM flights 
    WHERE YEAR(flights.DepartureDate) = YEAR(NEW.DepartureDate); 
    SET NEW.Name = flight_name;
END;
```

With these procedure I automatically set the name of the new flight according its year of departure

Answer (score 1):

If you are using (or can switch to) MyISAM Engine, you should use MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

To watch this working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6af9/1

```
CREATE TABLE flights (
  year ENUM('2013','2014','2015') NOT NULL,
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DepartureDate date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (year,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then insert as you were doing it before or like this:

```
INSERT INTO flights (year, DepartureDate) VALUES ('2013', date('2013-07-03')), 
('2014', date('2014-06-03')), ('2013', date('2013-02-06')), 
('2015', date('2015-01-04')), ('2015', date('2015-02-04')),
('2015', date('2015-12-10')), ('2015', date('2015-06-04')),
('2015', date('2015-11-04')), ('2015', date('2015-10-04')),
('2015', date('2015-01-07')), ('2015', date('2015-01-09')),
('2015', date('2015-01-09')), ('2015', date('2015-09-12')),
('2015', date('2015-02-09')), ('2015', date('2015-07-04'));
```

And when looking for records do something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(year, LPAD(id, 4, '0')) AS name, DepartureDate FROM flights;
```

For further reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I need the flight's name must be static once it would be created

Comment: This way the name won't ever change. The name will be the concatenation of two fields that have always the same value. If you always select like in the example, you will get always the same name for each record

Comment: My engine must be InnoDB @aLostMonkey

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure of what is your goal.

But just my guess:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dc5b/1

```
INSERT INTO flights 
SELECT 7, MAX(Name)+1, @d 
FROM flights
WHERE YEAR(DepartureDate)=YEAR(@d);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO flights 
SELECT 7, MAX(Name)+1, date('2013-05-04') 
FROM flights
WHERE YEAR(DepartureDate)=YEAR(date('2013-05-04'));
```

or if your `id` is already AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
INSERT INTO flights 
SELECT null, MAX(Name)+1, date('2013-05-04') 
FROM flights
WHERE YEAR(DepartureDate)=YEAR(date('2013-05-04'));
```